# ParseException for Solr query

Tags: magento, solr

I'm using Magento for search and have some filters set up to refine the search results.

If I do a simple search it returns results fine and Solr with  the following search request (Solr 3.6.2)

> path=/select
>   params={spellcheck=true&sort=score+desc&spellcheck.extendedResults=true&json.nl=map&wt=json&spellcheck.collate=true&version=1.2&rows=1&fl=id&start=0&q=collagen&spellcheck.dictionary=magento_spell_en&spellcheck.count=2&qt=magento_en&fq=(visibility:3+OR+visibility:4)+AND+store_id:1}

However, when I filter I get no results.  I have looked in the Solr logs and it seems that a parseException is being triggered by the search query that is being passed through (query below):

> path=/select
>   params={facet=on&sort=score+desc&json.nl=map&wt=json&version=1.2&rows=9999&facet.query=category_ids:3&facet.query=category_ids:5&facet.query=category_ids:6&facet.query=category_ids:7&facet.query=category_ids:8&facet.query=category_ids:11&facet.query=category_ids:58&facet.query=category_ids:10&start=0&q=collagen&facet.field={!ex%3Dbottle_size}attr_nav_select_bottle_size&facet.field={!ex%3Dconcern1}attr_nav_multi_concern1&facet.field={!ex%3Dskin_types}attr_nav_multi_skin_types&qt=magento_en&fq=(visibility:3+OR+visibility:4)+AND+({!tag%3Dconcern1}attr_nav_multi_concern1:29)+AND+store_id:1}

The error that is being logged is:

> Cannot parse '(visibility:3 OR visibility:4) AND
>   ({!tag=concern1}attr_nav_multi_concern1:29) AND store_id:1':
>   Encountered " "}" "} "" at line 1, column 50.

Can anyone see what is wrong with the query?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out in the end, we had an outdated extension that didn't work with the latest Magento enterprises Solr implementation.  Upgraded it and all is fine.

Comment: Hi Richard, what is the name of this outdated extension? It seems I'm having the same issue and I can't figure it out. Also, was it related to solr-config or schema.xml? Thanks.